# JQuery Mobile Error Loading Wicket BookmarkablePageLink

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile, jetty, wicket

I am new to JQuery Mobile.  I have an Apache Wicket-based application that I'd like to try JQuery Mobile on so it looks more pleasing on mobile devices.  Unfortunately, I am getting `"Error Loading Page"` errors for all the page links, which I never had problems with before switching to JQuery Mobile.  The root cause appears to be the URLs contained in the HTTP requests.  I used JQuery Mobile 1.2.0, JQuery 1.8.0, Wicket 1.5.5, locally tested using jetty server 6.1.26 and FireFox 16.0.  Here is the code snippet:

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
          <li><a href="#" wicket:id="metaprofileList" rel="external">List</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

The corresponding java code:

```
    add(new BookmarkablePageLink<MetaprofileListPage>(
            "metaprofileList", MetaprofileListPage.class));
```

Based on the above, Wicket correctly replaced `"#"` in `href="#"` with real URLs where the pages are, so the final HTML looks like the following:

```
        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="b">
          <li><a href="com.alcatel_lucent.nms8770.awol.client.web.page.MetaprofileListPage" wicket:id="metaprofileList" rel="external">List</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
```

When the link is clicked , Jetty server sends the following HTTP Request with the following URL:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:7999/com.alcatel_lucent.nms8770.awol.client.web.page.MetaprofileListPage [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 0ms]
```

This is not a correct URL for the MetaprofileListPage.  Before I switched to JQuery Mobile, I tested with the same scenario, the same jetty server send the following HTTP Request with the CORRECT url:

```
GET http://127.0.0.1:7999/wicket/bookmarkable/com.alcatel_lucent.nms8770.awol.client.web.page.MetaprofileListPage?7 [HTTP/1.1 200 OK 0ms]
```

The only change I did was switching the headers in the HTML file from:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/phone.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 480px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/default.css" media="only screen and (min-width: 1025px)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/portrait.css" media="all and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/landscape.css" media="all and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, width=device-width"/>
```

To the standard boilerplate jquery mobile includes:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
```

I have been struggling with this for 2 weeks now :-(  What do I need to do to get JQuery Mobile to work loading the correct urls/pages?  Please help!!  Many thanks!!

Comment: It looks like the Wicket URL renderer problem. The 'com.alcatel_lucent.nms8770.awol.client.web.page.MetaprofileListPage' is a wrong URL, because Wicket 1.5 default URL begins with 'wicket/bookmarkable/ You have to change anymore. Probably it looks that base url is defined or something so. Try to upgrade to the latest Wicket 1.5.10. Also try render full URL. Probably try to set base-url header element as workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should **mount** your bookmarkable pages under a short, well known segment, such as

- http://example.com/cheeses/edam
- http://example.com/profile

You do this typically in your override of the [Application#init](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.html#init%28%29) method, such as:

```
@Override
protected void init() {
    mountPage("/cheeses/${cheese}", CheesePage.class);
    mountPage("/profile", MyProfile.class);
}
```

This will at the very least remove those package names.